# Methods for a gradle file accesses another gradle file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have two gradle files:

first file:

```
 def sendMessage(String appName,String versionCode){
    println("${appName}---${versionCode}")
  }
```

second file:

```
afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.each { variant ->
       String variantName = variant.name.capitalize()
       def task = tasks.create("apkUploadPGY${variantName}")
       task.dependsOn("resguard${variantName}")
       task.doLast {
           //in this how can i use sendMessage function
      }
  }
}
```

I want to use the method defined in the first file in the second file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way:

**build.gradle**:

```
apply from: 'first.gradle'

task whatever {
    doLast {
        sendMessage("lol", "v1")
    }
}
```

**first.gradle**:

```
ext.sendMessage = { String appName, String versionCode ->
    println("${appName}--${versionCode}")
}
```

You also need to change `sendMessage` declaration. It should be defined as a groovy closure and stored within `ext` - this is how "methods" are used in gradle.